# Retrieve a table's fields from a lookup table dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, sql, schema

I am making a mysql/php project and in one form, the specs require dynamic fields in a way that you have an initial selectbox with a value from a lookup table that describe job unions. Depending on the selected value, it will spawn (probably via reflection) different fields.

For example, I have 2 associations with ids 1 and 2. If the user selects union #1, then the fields would be first name, last name, phone, address. If the user selects union #2 then the fields would be mobile, email, im name, "enroll now?"(checkbox).

Now, this might occur often, because the total of unions are more than 10 and specs require it to be flexible.

What I thought is this:

1. form loads up the fields of the first lookup (jobunions)
2. user selects the job union, and the value of the selectbox is the name of another table, for example LK_TABLE_2
3. The reflection examines the LK_TABLE_2 fields and retrieves/renders the fields below the selectbox of step 1.

I need your opinion on whether this business logic is acceptable (is there a pattern I could use?), if not anything to suggest and if it's doable how to store the filled data into the user preferences table.

Any insight would do.

Update: here is a schema (pdf) of what I am trying to do
https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B_vptVa0K8J2YjBjMGJmZDgtYzUxZi00ZTE5LTgxZjgtOTNlMjQ5OGM3ZTY1&hl=en_US

Comment: Without table schemata it's a bit hard to understand exactly what you're trying to do. I'll say this though... in my experience when the business says that the application needs to be "flexible" it actually means that they're too lazy or lack the business knowledge to actually define what they really want. Either way, it's a train-wreck waiting to happen.

Comment: No kidding, I have stories... Anyway, I am making a schema image now to help and will update my description.

Comment: @Panagiotis You do not mention any particular php framework, but it lends itself to a MVC pattern using partial views. The initial select box can be used to determine which partial view to load, which is already bound to your model for that selection. I imagine other php techniques to dynamically include partial views is available sans framework.

Comment: Your entire question is hard for me to understand. You lost me at the 2nd paragraph.

Comment: First comment is spot on. You should try to agree some limitations and boundaries to help narrow the scope of the problem. Id also add its not often a great idea to use table names as a way of differentiating the selects. Try to add them into a common table schema and reference them by ids (or tuples etc)

Comment: me too not very clear with your question description but if i answer only the title of your question then this query might help you. 
SELECT column_name FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "DBName" AND table_name = "TableName"
in mysql we information_schema database which has information of all the database,tables & columns.

Comment: Actually I implemented with another way. But it's irrelevant now, the project/service that was needed, was terminated due to insufficient funds. So I am going to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am closing this question, because of the project that was terminated, and further more I don't work in the specific company anymore (over half a year ago).

We jumped to a more nosql solution before this happened and it was working fine... until termination.